# How to show custom query result to view mvc3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have Custom query Result as

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Query = (from E in db.SITE_MASTER.AsEnumerable()
                         where E.IS_PAGE == true
                         select new 
                         {
                             E.POST_TITLE,
                             E.POST_TEXT
                         }).ToList();
            return View(Query);
        }
```

Now,

How can I make view for this result or How can I create View for this Result Query.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an anonymous type as a model, but please don't. It's ugly and will lead to maintenance problems.

As an alternative either use the `ViewBag` or create concrete type and pass that.